# Generate a Prediction List

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

With Tensorflow, is there a go to way to output the networks predictions?

My Outputs have been using a One Hot Representation for 12 classes

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
etc...
```

When trying to get predictions out of my model for a given input, I ran the following code

```
    prediction=tf.argmax(y,1)
    best = sess.run([prediction],feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                  seqlen: batch_seqlen})
    print("Prediction: ")
    print(best)
```

My output when I ran this code and printed the prediction was:

```
[array([1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 9, 4, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 3, 2], dtype=int64)]
```

my batch size that I input was 16, so it did make sense to have 16 outputs. However, none of these are One Hot representation (Not sure if tensorflow's output is intended to be interperated as index's, so the 1 would actually be some form of onehot

Is there a way for each particular X to create a ranked list of predictions, what the model finds the most likely given that X?

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You're taking the `tf.argmax` of 1-hot vectors, so that's why you're seeing indices instead of the 1-hot vectors you expected.

To get a sorted list of class predictions you could take your prediction vector and apply `values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(prediction)` the `values` will be your predictions sorted in DESCENDING order and `indices` will be those sorted `values`' indices.